# C# events in interfaces - confusion from a vb.net programer

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, interface

I'm having some real confusion about events in c#... if I have this code in an interface:

```
Event OnBeforeSaving(ByVal Sender As TEntity, ByVal EventArgs As CancelEventArgs)
```

How should it be in c#? When I run it through a converter it gives me this

```
event OnBeforeSavingEventHandler OnBeforeSaving;
delegate void OnBeforeSavingEventHandler(TEntity Sender, CancelEventArgs EventArgs);
```

I'm not sure if I understand what is going on... in my head the code should be combined. Is this correct?

```
event OnBeforeSaving(TEntity Sender, CancelEventArgs EventArgs);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm not sure if I understand what is going on... in my head the code should be combined. Is this correct?

No.  In VB.NET, you can combine this on a single line.  The Event keyword allows you to specify the full signature of the delegate type being handled.

In C#, however, you need to explicitly tell the event which type of delegate it will use.  If it's not a standard delegate type, then you have to declare the delegate, as well.  This is what your converter is doing for you.

That being said, in this case, this:

```
delegate void OnBeforeSavingEventHandler(TEntity Sender, CancelEventArgs EventArgs);
event OnBeforeSavingEventHandler OnBeforeSaving;
```

Probably should be replaced with this:

```
event EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> OnBeforeSaving;
```

This is because there is a built-in [`EventHandler<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) type in the framework, that follows the suggested pattern for events, which specifies that the sender should be an **System.Object**, and the EventArgs should be a subclass of [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx).  This is not quite the same as your VB.NET code, however, since you were restricting the sender to a `TEntity` type.

Even better would be to use the built-in [CancelEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventhandler.aspx) type:

```
event CancelEventHandler OnBeforeSaving;
```

This is basically identical to `EventHandler<CancelEventArgs>`, but more expected, since there is a framework event handler type specifically for cancellation.

Comment: `CancelEventArgs` does have a specific matching delegate type. Users familiar with this event will likely put `+= new CancelEventHandler...` based on prior experience: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventhandler.aspx

Comment: True, good point... In this case, though, it wouldn't have worked before either ;)  but here, using CancelEventHandler would make the most sense.

Comment: Not to nitpick (ok maybe to nitpick, but I already voted it up), but the event should be called `BeforeSaving`, and there should be a `protected virtual void OnBeforeSaving(CancelEventArgs e)` method that invokes it.

Comment: @280Z28: Your first comment (about the event name) should be made to the original poster, who named it in VB as OnBeforeSaving.

Comment: @280Z28: +1, and yes, I agree completely - but again, I was trying to follow the OP's naming...

Comment: Yeah I know. :) Surprised you didn't call me back on the name - I believe either `BeforeSave` or simply `Saving` are the best choices?

Comment: @280Z28: I personally would use Saving and Saved, and provide both events (to correspond to closing/closed, etc).

Answer (score 1):

.Net requires events to be of a Delegate type.

The VB compiler will automatically create a delegate type; the C# compiler forces you to create it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
event EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> OnBeforeSaving;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
delegate void OnBeforeSavingEventHandler(TEntity Sender, CancelEventArgs EventArgs);
```

defines a new type called "OnBeforeSavingEventHandler". It is a delegate type, which defines a method call that takes TEntity and CancelEventArgs parameters and returns nothing.

This line:

```
event OnBeforeSavingEventHandler OnBeforeSaving;
```

declares a class member that is an event called "OnBeforeSaving". This event is of type "OnBeforeSavingEventHandler". Therefore, any objects that wish to subscribe to this event must have a method that is compatible with the "OnBeforeSavingEventHandler" delegate type.